# Button after ListBox

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I need to show `ListBox` with dynamic content (so I do not know its height) and `Button` below it. So user should be able to scroll ListBox to end and see button.

In Android I would use `RelativeLayout` and `below` property for button or some other solution, but in WP I do not know how to do it.

What I had tryed:

1) Put all in `StackPanel`

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox />
    <Button />
</StackPanel>
```

**This is not working, because StackPanel is blocking ListBox scrolling.**

2) Ok, lets put ListBox in Grid

```
<StackPanel>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox />
    </Grid>
    <Button />
</StackPanel>
```

Nothing happens.

3) Put all in Grid and use Grid.Row not worked.

4) Lets put all in `Grid` and set margin for `Button` dynamically

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox />
    <Button />
</Grid>
```

**Ok, this is working, but it is not good solution , because I need to handle `ListBox`populating each time and reset margin for button. Bad bad bad.**

P.S. Also, I can put button as ListBox item (not bad, but not good :)

Help me please...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you need a simple Grid defined like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListBox />
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Height="80"/>
</Grid>
```

By making height of the row zero to "star" and the first row to Auto, the ListBox will fill the remaining space, and the Button only 80 (you can change this to whatever you like). ListBox is automatically put to row zero because that's the default if it is not explicitly set.

If you don't want the button fixed on the page but to scroll with the ListBox, you could edit the ListBox template like this:

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxWithButtonStyle" TargetType="ListBox">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                        <Button Content="Touch me" Height="80" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And then apply to ListBox:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <ListBox Style="{StaticResource ListBoxWithButtonStyle}">

    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I had tryed your solution, but `Button` is visible always, I need to show button only when user scrolls `ListBox` to end, just like if button would be last ListBox item

Comment: Wow, tons of code for easy task :) Why Silverlight is so ugly... Ok, I`ll try it :)

Comment: It's not that awful actually. The template code is pretty much alrady there, all you need to do is change what's inside the ScrollViewer, and that's only 3-4 lines of code!

Comment: Well, if you declared the template inside the Page resources, you could just add the Click event handler and handle it in the Page.xaml.cs code behind!

Comment: I Had moved style to page xaml, thank you! But I still think that silverlight is ugly :)

Comment: For future reference, it's easier to accomplish this with the `LongListSelector` control. You can [easily add to the footer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.longlistselector.listfootertemplate(v=vs.105).aspx) or [detect when you reach the end of the list](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/TwitterSearch-Windows-b7fc4e5e)